# How long it takes to get ATAS?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am applying as student research student for next month and I do not know if can get before 16th January?

Comment: What is ATAS ??

Answer (score 1):

Highly unlikely.

UK guidance states that when you have received your offer from your university you should apply for your Academic Technology Approval Scheme certificate **6 months** before your course will start.

If you’re a new student and need an ATAS certificate, you will need to get this before applying for permission to enter the UK.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/academic-technology-approval-scheme